# How to avoid `all` function returning `TRUE` when comparing to `NULL` or an empty object

Tags: r

I often use `all` function and, whenever I get `TRUE`, I find myself checking that none of the elements of the comparison is `NULL` or empty because this could give a false `TRUE` result.

Example:

```
y<-1:10
z<-5:15

# I make a comparison which is really true
all(y[y>5 & y<10]==z[z>5 & z<10]) 
[1] TRUE

# Now I make a typo because I often do, but I don't notice:
all(y[y>5 & y<0]==z[z>5 & z<10])
[1] TRUE
# the result is also true but only because y[y>5 & y<0] is empty:
y[y>5 & y<0]
#integer(0)
```

So, in the second case, if I don't check each element of `all`, I will go one with my code, thinking everything went well and, of course, the final result will be incorrect.

Instead of checking the element I put in my `all` call, I could add a `length` call: `(all(y[y>5 & y<0]==z[z>5 & z<10]) & length(y[y>5 & y<0])>0 & length(z[z>5 & z<10]>0)` but that seems rather tedious...

Is there a way to make `all` return `NA` or `FALSE` when either element is of length 0 (`all` help is not very helpful on that subject) or is there an alternative function that would do that ?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Metrics, there is an alternative with function `identical`:

```
identical(y[y>5 & y<0],z[z>5 & z<10])
[1] FALSE
```

Although `identical`doesn't return `TRUE` in this case, it still doesn't warn me that something is going wrong...

The ideal solution would return a warning telling, for example, that one element is empty.

Comment: I think if you used a [proper style guide (with specific detail to spacing)](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml#spacing), you may avoid making such typos

Comment: how about `identical`?

Comment: @rawr thanks for the link but I don't think that is the solution. I usually make typos when variable names are long and complicated (but there might be a solution to avoid using those variable names to). Anyway, it is not necessary typos the problem, I can end up with an empty object even without making typos ;-)

Comment: @Metrics, thanks, that indeed seems to be an interesting alternative to `all`. Still, you'll get `FALSE` but no warning that objects are not of same length for example

Comment: "variable names are long and complicated" there are also notes about those things in that guide

Comment: @rawr, yes and I totally see your point of view and agree but that's not really the thing I want to resolve here (although, I promise I'm gonna read this guide)

Comment: I know im beating a dead horse, but that is what your question said. avoiding typos. to actually be helpful for once, `all.equal` would be  better than identical and also give you a warning about why rather than just FALSE, closer to your "ideal" answer: `all.equal(.) [1] "Numeric: lengths (0, 4) differ"
`

Comment: @rawr, alright, I admit, I need this mostly because of typos and so, avoiding typos will very likely resolve my problem ;-). Thanks for mentioning `all.equal`, it is indeed closer to what I am looking for !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for `all` clearly says:

> That all(logical(0)) is true is a useful convention: it ensures that
>
> all(all(x), all(y)) == all(x, y) even if x has length zero.

so there is no way to obtain your desired result with `all`.

As noted in the comments, `identical` and `all.equal` are closer matches to your request. However, `identical` wouldn't warn you if the objects under comparison are of different length. The drawback of `all.equal` is that it wouldn't return you a logical value in the case of different lengths:

```
all.equal(y[y>5 & y<0],z[z>5 & z<10])
# [1] "Numeric: lengths (0, 4) differ"
```

and I believe that the official documentation suggests not to use `all.equal` directly in `if` expressions:

> Do not use all.equal directly in if expressions—either use
>   isTRUE(all.equal(....)) or identical if appropriate.

However, `isTRUE(all.equal(y[y>5 & y<0],z[z>5 & z<10]))` wouldn't tell you about different lengths.

**[Solution]**

You can simply write your own function for this purpose and add some syntactic sugar for convenience:

```
'%=%' <- function(a,b) {
   if (length(a)!=length(b)) warning('Objects are of different length')
   identical(a,b)
 }
```

It will return `TRUE` if the objects are identical

```
y[y>5 & y<10]  %=%  z[z>5 & z<10]
# [1] TRUE
```

and `FALSE` if the objects are different (+warning if they are of different length):

```
y[y>5 & y<0]  %=%  z[z>5 & z<10]
#  [1] FALSE
#  Warning message:
#    In y[y > 5 & y < 0] %=% z[z > 5 & z < 10] :
#    Objects are of different length
```

Comment: Thank you for this very complete and detailed answer. I guess the better solution is indeed a homemade operator that merges qualities of both `all.equal` and `identical` functions

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should use either `identical` or `all.equal` for this purpose. As already outlined, the latter doesn't return always a logical vector, while the first is much more stringent and should be used only to check if two objects are really the same. Consider this example:

```
y<-setNames(1:10,letters[1:10])
z<-5:15
identical(y[y>5 & y<10],z[z>5 & z<10])
```

it gives `FALSE` because `y` has names. The `all` function is the way to go. If you are really bothered about the zero length issue, try:

```
myAll <- function(x,na.rm=FALSE) {
   if (length(x)==0) {
      warning("zero length argument")
      return(TRUE)
   }
   all(x,na.rm=na.rm)
}
```

Of course you can change the behaviour when `x` has zero length or you can define a binary operator as already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I upvoted because it pointed out the problem of `identical` in case of equal values but different names but I don't really understand the point of your `myAll` function.

Comment: Aren't you bothered of the fact that `all` returns `TRUE` when its argument is of zero length? Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Yes but when comparing to something else, like `all(NULL==1:10)` but not just `all(NULL)` but maybe I'm misunderstanding your function ?

Comment: What you mean comparing to something else? Do you realise that the `all` function takes a logical vector and checks if all the elements are `TRUE`? It doesn't need two arguments. Maybe you don't have clear the difference between checking if two objects are identical and if the values of each element of two vectors are the same.

Comment: I just mean `all(x==y)` and the problem is if either `x` or `y` is empty

Comment: And `myAll` function solves this issue with a warning, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake, I did misunderstand your function, which is indeed very helpful, although, I'd rather have `FALSE` as a result. Thanks again for your answer