# Compare a value to null. Why is this true?

Tags: r, null, logical-operators

Why is

```
isTRUE(NULL != 2)
[1] FALSE
```

And how would I receive TRUE?

In my real case I have variables and I want to process something, if the values differ. However, when one value is NULL I don't recognize them as different!

Comment: You can't compare with NULL. You need is.null to test if something is a reference to the NULL object.

Comment: To get the value you expect you would: `isTRUE(!is.null(2))`

Comment: @CarlesMitjans the variable is not always NULL, normally it has another integer value. It's only rarely that it has NULL. It's inconvenient, but I added another is.null() check before. I don't get this, though. Other languages do fine here.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28502037/4137985

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592148/compare-if-two-dataframe-objects-in-r-are-equal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare if two dataframe objects in R are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592148/compare-if-two-dataframe-objects-in-r-are-equal)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Roland pointed out, we can't perform any logical operations directly on `NULL` object. To compare them we might need to perform an additional check of `is.null` and then perform the logical comparison.

We can use `identical` instead to compare values which handles integers as well as `NULL`.

```
identical(4, 2) 
#FALSE

identical(NULL, 2) 
#FALSE

identical(2, 2) 
#TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer the **why** part of your question:

Comparing `NULL` with other types will give you `logical(0)` (i.e., a logical vector of length zero). So,

```
isTRUE(NULL != 2)
```

actually is

```
isTRUE(logical(0))
```

which is `FALSE`.

In order to compare the values where you might have `NULL` values also, you could also do something like this (using short circuit logical operator):

```
a <- 2
b <- 2
!is.null(a) && !is.null(b) && a==b
#[1] TRUE

a <- 3
b <- 2
!is.null(a) && !is.null(b) && a==b
#[1] FALSE

a <- 2
b <- NULL
!is.null(a) && !is.null(b) && a==b
#[1] FALSE
```