# Creating a vector from other objects using 'for loop'

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have these object (I have thousands of [[i]], this is just an example):

```
v
```

[[1]]
1 2 3 4

[[2]]
5 6 7 8

I want to create a new vector (column) like this:

```
vector
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

,using a for loop. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
vector=c()
for(i in 1:2){
    vector[i]=v[[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the input data is a `list`.  So we need to `unlist` it

```
v1 <- unlist(v)
v1
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

If we need a `for` loop

```
v2 <- c()
for(i in seq_along(v)) v2 <- c(v2, v[[i]])
```

#### data

```
v <- list(1:4, 5:8)
```

Comment: I want to use a for loop, I have thousands of [[i]]-s, so I want a faster process...

Comment: @Ari `unlist` is a faster option

Comment: `do.call(c, v)` but don't you think there is a dupe for this somewhere?

Comment: @Sotos There could be, just like the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774483/compare-a-value-to-null-why-is-this-true)

Comment: Ok. No worries. I will find a dupe

Comment: @Sotos Okay, no worries,

Comment: sorry guys!!! You were right! I am just a beginner!